# Convert APK to manifest in a loop

Tags: android, batch-file, cmd, apktool

I have many APK (Android package) files in a folder and I want to extract the manifest files from each of them. I am using Android apktool to convert them and since there are many APK files I want to convert them in a loop, not one by one.

`apktool d hello.apk ./hello` is the command for extracting manifest files from `hello.apk` and produces the output folder named `hello`.

I tried the command in the command prompt using for loop in the current directory in which all APK files are stored:

```
for \r %v in (*.apk) do apktool d "%v" "./%v".
```

I want the output folder of same name for each APK file, i.e. if APK is `hello.apk` the output folder should be `hello`. The above command is producing an error: cannot generate the output folder. How can I extract manifest files from all such APK files at once from a loop?

Comment: Can you post whole batch code?

Comment: `for /r %v in (*.apk) do apktool d "%v" "./%~Nv"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you forgot `-o` parameter?

That command works fine for me:

```
for /r %v in (*.apk) do apktool.jar d "%v" -o "./%~Nv"
```

Comment: Can you accept an answer, if it solves your problem?